# Add Variable to .NET MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, model-binding

This seems to be a very basic question, but I have not been able to find an answer.  I'm attempting to define a variable in one of my controller classes in order to take a "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself) approach to my [Bind(Include=...)] attribute settings for my action methods.

I'm attempting to do this:

```
// Make the accessible fields more DRY
List<string> field_access = new List<string>();
field_access.Add("Title");
field_access.Add("Author");
field_access.Add("Genre");
field_access.Add("Level");
```

...

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = field_access)] Song song)
```

Instead of this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Author,Genre,Level")] Song song)
```

Here's the error:
CS1519  Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

An guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: In case you are white listing the fields you wish to bind, you might want to consider using a `view model` instead, as [well explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Where are the `Title`, `Author`, etc. values coming from? Are they being posted from the client? Are they route values or query string values in the URL? Other?

Comment: Thanks @LennartStoop, but my application needs to manage the primary key of table associated with the model since I'm not having that done at the db level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error CS1519 means that you have some invalid token in your code.

You don't need to use a list in this case. You can create a constant in your controller and then use it on the attribute:

```
public class SongsController : Controller
{
    private const string FieldAccess = "ID,Title,Author,Genre,Level";

    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = FieldAccess)] Song song)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Fabiano!  This solved the problem.  I think the problem was where I was declaring the string.  I had it outside of my controller class code block and in the namespace area, and the namespace didn't like that at all.  With this approach I can declare the  list in one place and have over-posting protection when I create and update.  One list to manage.  Thanks again.